# Error on deactivating process builder from unlocked package

Tags: process-builder

We have process builders installed from unlocked package.

Until now everything worked perfectly (besides the old known issues that you cannot see body of process builder from installed package), but today we tried deactivating couple of process builder and we got error like in screen.

[image]

Anyone know anything about this issue, any workaround? Or we are left with contacting support...

Comment: Ok I think its connected to this known issue but just want to be sure:
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000BMOWQA4&title=getting-internal-server-error-when-trying-to-fetch-process-definitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question was connected to Salesforce Known issue, which was already resolved.

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000BMOWQA4&title=getting-internal-server-error-when-trying-to-fetch-process-definitions